# Передача объекта А в класс В и вызов его метода, и наоборот

Tags: c++

Ошибка при передаче объекта В в класс А. Подскажите как решить такую проблему.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout << "A" << endl;
        }

        void print(B* b)
        {
            b->print();
        }
};

class B
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout << "B" << endl;
        }

        void print(A* a)
        {
            a->print();
        }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();
    a->print(b);
    b->print(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
    void print(B* b);
};

class B
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
    void print(A* a)
    {
        a->print();
    }
};

void A::print(B* b)
{
    b->print();
}

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();
    a->print(b);
    b->print(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Класс B объявляется перед объявлением класса A, чтобы его можно было использовать в методах класса A.

Comment: То есть, чтобы такое работало следует писать реализацию функции вне класса? И правильно ли я понимаю, что лучше всегда раздельно писать раздельно описание класса и реализацию его функций?

Comment: нет, нужно просто предварительная объявление класса. и второе - нет.

Comment: Смотрите, в классе А надо знать, что такое В. Объявляя `class B;`, мы говорим, что будет такой класс - потом. **Указатель** на него можно использовать сразу - его размер известен, а больше пока ничего не надо. Но там, где вызывается `b->print()`, уже надо знать, что такое этот класс, есть ли в нем такая функция, какая она... Так что такой вызов нужно разместить уже после определения класса `B` - приходится его выносить... Так понятнее?

Comment: Писать ли объявление и реализацию раздельно - зависит от конкретной ситуации. Требования такого нет. Как нет и требования писать реализацию в классе - это фактически аналог описать вне с ключевым словом `inline`.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо!!! Вы мне очень помогли!!